# nested set - Get ID from last sub entry with MySQL

Tags: mysql, query

I need the last Child item ID from this nested set table
So i would need ID 4,10,11,16 or "rgt" values in this Example
What i found is just the query below.

THis is what the table looks like:

```
+----+---------+----------------+-----+-----+
| id | root_id | LongName       | lft | rgt |
+----+---------+----------------+-----+-----+
|  1 |       1 | Clothes        |   1 |   8 |
|  2 |       1 | Boys           |   2 |   3 |
|  3 |       1 | Girls          |   4 |   5 |
|  4 |       1 | Gender neutral |   6 |   7 |
|  5 |       5 | Toys           |   1 |  14 |
|  6 |       5 | Boys           |   2 |   3 |
|  7 |       5 | Girls          |   4 |   5 |
|  8 |       5 | Gender neutral |   6 |   7 |
|  9 |       5 | Shoes          |   8 |  11 |
| 10 |       5 | Toys_TEST      |   9 |  10 |
| 11 |       5 | Buggys         |  12 |  13 |
| 12 |      12 | Maternity Wear |   1 |  10 |
| 13 |      12 | Trousers       |   2 |   3 |
| 14 |      12 | Nursing Bra    |   4 |   5 |
| 15 |      12 | Dresses        |   6 |   9 |
| 16 |      12 | Skirts         |   7 |   8 |
+----+---------+----------------+-----+-----+
```

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `nest` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `root_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `LongName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lft` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `rgt` bigint(11) NOT NULL
)
```

Table Data:

```
INSERT INTO `nest` (`id`, `root_id`, `LongName`, `lft`, `rgt`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Clothes', 1, 8),
(2, 1, 'Boys', 2, 3),
(3, 1, 'Girls', 4, 5),
(4, 1, 'Gender neutral', 6, 7),
(5, 5, 'Toys', 1, 14),
(6, 5, 'Boys', 2, 3),
(7, 5, 'Girls', 4, 5),
(8, 5, 'Gender neutral', 6, 7),
(9, 5, 'Shoes', 8, 11),
(10, 5, 'Toys_TEST', 9, 10),
(11, 5, 'Buggys', 12, 13),
(12, 12, 'Maternity Wear', 1, 10),
(13, 12, 'Trousers', 2, 3),
(14, 12, 'Nursing Bra', 4, 5),
(15, 12, 'Dresses', 6, 9),
(16, 12, 'Skirts', 7, 8);
```

my query so far:

```
select root_id, max(rgt) as max_rgt
from (
    select * from nesttable where rgt - lft = 1
) as TT
group by root_id
```

with the result:

```
+---------+---------+
| root_id | max_rgt |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       7 |
|       5 |      13 |
|      12 |       8 |
+---------+---------+
```

the Result should look like:

```
+---------+---------+
| root_id | max_rgt |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       7 |
|       5 |      10 |
|       5 |      13 |
|      12 |       8 |
+---------+---------+
```

the best thing would be if i get the IDs from the last children.
Something like this would be perfect:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  4 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 16 |
+----+
```

From this table i need the id 4,10,11,16 or rgt values of this child but i just got rgt values of ID 4,11,16 with this Query.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Please consider reading [ask] in the Help Centre. The community prefers you to post the table definitions and table data as text, as it allows us to reuse the data and do our own testing. Posting screenshots is counterproductive. You might also want to read [mcve] to help you understand how to ask good questions. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by last, is it all leafs? Can you explain why 10 should be included in the result, but not 3?

Comment: I already found a solution in php with  the levels of the table,
thx anyway

Comment: Glad to know that someone found a solution in PHP, most people only find problems there;-)